# Display RSS feed using pagination

Tags: rss

I want to display posts from another WordPress installation on my WordPress site. Both installations are on different servers so I thought the best approach would be using RSS to display the posts.

There are 50+ posts to show so I want to display 10 posts per page and use pagination (just like WordPress does for regular posts). Can this be achieved using RSS?

Thanks for your help!